# how to insert a visible box around a set of content in latex?

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm trying to figure out how the books draw a box perhaps with different background around a digression/example? Preferably how this would be accomplished in lyx, but latex solution would be welcomed as well :D

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `color` package should allow you to use the `\colorbox` command.

Examples (cited from [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190219184356/http://www.math.harvard.edu/computing/latex/color.html), where you will find more details):

```
\colorbox{red}{Black text on red background}

\fcolorbox{blue}{red}%
  {Black text, red background, blue frame}
```

If you need just a border and no background color, the built-in `\fbox{text}` command should do fine.

Answer (score 6):

In Lyx you can do Insert -> Box. This creates a Box (Minipage) and you can put your content inside it. When you right click the Box (Minipage) and go to Settings, you can select type of the border or even drop shadow or shaded background via 'Decoration'. (This should be accessible directly through the right click menu as well.)

Hope this helps :)